# why require need .js extension while importing js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, systemjs, commonjs

I am trying  to implement CommonJS patten using below link

https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-module-system-commonjs-require/

I am getting error **file not found error** why ?
here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/mYeCYw9MOr87b4dQZr5I?p=preview
Error is present on this line 
`const add = require('./login')`

when I added .js after `login` it works but In example it doesn't add `.js` extension why ? most of time i used require with `js` extension.

```
const add = require('./login')

console.log(add(4, 5))
```

Comment: So your doe works with `.js` extension. Why not continue with that?

Comment: By the way, RequireJS, CommonJS and SystemJS are different frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue being able to omit the `.js` extension you can use the `defaultExtension` option in your SystemJS configuration. If I add this to your plunker, it loads without error:

```
SystemJS.config({
  packages: {
    '': {
      defaultExtension: "js"
    }
  }
})
```

This defines a package that encompasses all your code and for which the default extension, if not specified in the module request, is `.js`.

Answer (score 0):

According to SystemJS examples, you have to put the whole path (including extension).

You can check here:

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs